# How to host your own icons

Tags: html, css

I've been using Font Awesome for a little bit on some of my projects and I have created a bunch of my own icons that I can link locally without a problem; however, I want to be able to link the icons I made from an online source like Font Awesome do and serve them publicly, how exactly is this achieved?

Comment: Turn them into a font using an online service and put them on a CDN.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't believe this is programming related. This is about how to offer a service.

Comment: No I'm not, I've given you an answer and this isn't about programming. Carry on with that attitude and no one will help you

Comment: Well in a way it is, I needed to know how to make it so I can link online font sources to my html files rather than just from my local files. Your answer wasn't really that helpful either, what CDN can I put them on? I already have them as fonts I just need to know how they're uploaded and used.

Comment: all you need is a CDN service, as Andy said. Get one, upload your icons there and you won't have to offend people trying to help you

Comment: I'm sure you can research based on the information gudboisgn and I have given you; you can also create your own CDN and serve your files from there. So no, it's still not about programming; it's how to offer a service/product via an online platform

Comment: I offend people? I only just get this account, ask a question and already my question is being voted to be closed... That's pretty rude...

Comment: It's not rude at all, calling someone a dick is rude. SO has question guidelines and this doesn't fall into it at the moment so it's voted to be closed based on that. Besides, we've literally given you all the information you need

Comment: pretty rude is to be lazy ass, and expecting others to do the research for you. You got what you need, all you gotta do now is to do some googling, choose service suits you the best and you're done. And Andy is actually right, this is not programming related question.

Comment: I've spent the last several hours researching things and haven't really reached anything useful. I thought I'd come here because it seemed like a helpful community and my question is met with with complete insolent condescension. That is pretty rude, but I've got my response, I'm done, thanks for your overwhelmingly kind welcome.

Comment: Isaac, dude, what part of my first comment and the other comments that mention CDN aren't us being helpful as a community? You also called me a dick, yet you seem to enjoy ignoring this fact and think everyone is against you...

Comment: Your first comment was fine! Brilliant even! Though straight off the bat I seem to be dealt with the negativity, now that I look at it yes what I said was uncalled for - I apologise - I've been up all night tirelessly trying to get some answers and I've finally decided to ask for myself and I read some hostility into your second comment - I'm a little flustered at the moment.

Comment: The second comment isn't hostility, *"I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because"* is generated from SO's system, you then have to put in a reason and the reason is accurate. You wish to offer a service, but that isn't about programming. Thank you for the apology. Make your font using the answer below and find a CDN that will offer the files for you - all you need to do

Comment: Yes, yes I know, it's very late here I'm frustrated as I haven't had any luck in the research I've done and it took all of 5 seconds for my question to be negatively voted and asked to be kicked off, I was just looking for a push in the right direction - you've clarified things - now I'll try and find a CDN. My font was already made I just need a place to put it.

Comment: Check out the answer I've just added, see if that helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit of Googling for you to find somewhere for your to offer your files.

You will need to create a font from your SVG files, I use [fontastic.me](http://fontastic.me) and it's very good, but you could use another service.

You will then need to create a package of your files, and put it on a CDN service so that other people (or just you) can use it publicly. You can try using something like https://www.jsdelivr.com/ or look into how to set up your own CDN.

Comment: Thank you, this was exceedingly helpful. I'm sorry we got off on the wrong foot!

Comment: No problem at all, welcome to SO. I hope things are a bit smoother from here! Don't take things too personally though, we just have to keep the questions on topic etc. If it's helped please upvote & accept (tick icon next to the question)

Comment: I don't normally take things personally, this has just been a frustrating night - I usually manage to figure things out for myself but this time it couldn't be done. I'm totally the dick. :L But thanks for everything I hope one day we can be friends and I'll buy you a drink or something.

Comment: We all have nights like those ;) I was the same when I joined SO haha. No problem at all, thank you for accepting :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have icon in SVG format that you have created,
then you can use this, it will generate all the necessary font types, CSS/Sass/Less/Stylus , HTML demo page and Name font according to your wish.

[Gruntt Web Font](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-webfont)

Comment: *"I want to be able to link the icons I made from an online source like Font Awesome do"* - You haven't answered the question yet

Comment: what do you mean by link. You want to host your font to CDN?

Comment: I'm not the OP but FontAwesome offer their font as a download but also via CDN services. Your answer is good, explain how to offer it publicly and it'll be worth a +1